# System.out closed? Can I reopen it?

Tags: java, io

I was helping a friend to write some Java code, who doesn't know a lot about Java. So I wrote him some helper functions to easily get things done that are a little quirky in his eyes. One of them is a function, that writes a String to an `OutputStream`. Have a look:

```
public void write(String txt, OutputStream out) {
    PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(out);
    printer.print(txt);
    printer.close();
}
```

Now, you can use that easily in different ways to write wherever you want. For example you could do that:

```
(new StreamHelper()).write("Hello Test", System.out);
```

Doing that I found out that afterwards `System.out.println()` doesn't write anything to the shell anymore. So I think that maybe `printer.close()` automatically also closed `System.out` and I wonder how to reactivate it that I can use it after this function is finished again.

Is my assumption correct? (How could I have found out without asking here?)

How can I continue to use `System.out` after a call to the `write()` function?

Are there better ways to write such a helper function?

Comment: I believe, you can use `flush` instead of `close()`.

Comment: You can make the `write` method `static` to avoid the ugly `(new StreamHelper()).write(...)` call.

Comment: @Stas Kurilin: I tried it and it works.

Comment: Stas why don't you make an answer out of this so erikb can accept it?

Comment: @Urs Reupke, now he can accept yours) Actually, there should be good comment not just suggestion for answer.

Comment: I accepted fortrans answer because it solves the problem in code and also explains the situation. It seems to be the most complete answer by now.

Comment: @adarshr no need to make write static, you could get rid of the extra parentheses even if the method isn't static. `new StreamHelper().write(...)` should do the same thing.

Comment: @TimBüthe Thanks, but I know that. I'm not sure why I said that about static though :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The general contract for `OutputStream`'s close:

> public void close()
>              throws IOException Closes this output stream and releases any system resources associated with this stream. The general contract
>   of close is that it closes the output stream. A closed stream cannot
>   perform output operations and **cannot be reopened**.

`PrintStream`'s

> public void close() Close the stream. This is done by flushing the
>   stream and then **closing the underlying output stream**.

The only advice I can give you is that you should not write [asymmetrical code](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AsymmetricalCode), that is, don't delegate the closing of resources your code has created to somewhere else.

Even if in your case it might seemed sensible to close the wrapper stream, the fact is that you should not because you are closing a stream opened somewhere else.

In short:

```
public void write(String txt, OutputStream out) {
    PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(out);
    printer.print(txt);
    printer.flush();
    //it is very unpolite to close someone else's streams!
    //printer.close();
}
```

Oh, and by the way, you may want to change the function name to `print`, rather than `write`.

Comment: I think it contains an answer and also a solution to the problem. Thanks for everybody's help!

Comment: In short: don't close what you didn't open.

Answer (score 13):

Like the others have said, a stream should be closed where it was opened. However, you could write a facade to protect a stream from getting closed like this:

```
import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class UnclosableOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

    public UnclosableOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
new StreamHelper().write("Hello Test", new UnclosableOutputStream(System.out));
```

Might come in handy for test scenarios etc.

Answer (score 3):

`System.out` is a PrintStream, therefore the code you provide above has literally no advantage over just calling `System.out.print` directly. The reason it is not writing anymore is that `close` did, in fact, close `System.out`.

If this is for logging, learn log4j for your friend or help him learn it. Log4j handles situations where you need to write to a file stream, standard out, etc. simultaneously quite well.

Comment: Not quite. It has the advantage of abstraction, in that you can use System.out as well as any other stream.

Comment: Unless he has a use case where that abstraction might be actually needed, such as logging, it's just pointless.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the `out` input being passed is `System.out` and selectively decide not to close.

The `flush()` call is necessary. Note that I am doing `==` check since the references will be identical if you were to invoke this `write` method with a `System.out` argument.

```
public void write(String txt, OutputStream out) {
    PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(out);
    printer.print(txt);
    printer.flush();

    if(out != System.out) {
        printer.close();
    }
}
```

But honestly, I would keep a different method for closing or call this method `writeAndClose` in order to avoid the confusion.

If you want to maintain abstraction (as hinted by @Urs), do the below. But I don't see the point of this rather *over-engineering*

```
public void write(String txt, OutputStream out) {
    PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(out);
    printer.print(txt);
    printer.flush();
}

public void close(OutputStream out) {
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Breaks with the abstraction the original solution created.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to try the output on JVM console, you'd better to get a Console instance with `System.console()`. And then get the `PrintWriter` with `console.writer()` method. After using the `PrintWriter`, you can close it. Based on the console description of JavaDoc,

> Invoking `close()` on the objects returned by the `reader()` and the
>   `writer()` will not close the underlying stream of those objects.

You can do this again and again. No need to worrying about reopen the stream.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this from the caller's point of view.

The caller has an `OutputStream` of some sort, and calls a method called `write()`. After the call completes, the caller discovers that the stream has been closed.

In my view, your `write()` method simply should not call `printer.close()`. The latter closes the stream provided by the caller and is probably not what the caller expects.

If you need to flush the stream, you could use `flush()`.

Answer (score 2):

Do what Stas Kurilin suggests.

In general, streams should be closed by the party that opened/created them.

In your method, just flush the stream. Close it wherever it was opened when it is no longer needed.