# Console output not working after method call

Tags: java, console, output, printstream

I'm currently working on an application that generates and validates .xml files based on some template files.

The method I call to generate those files goes like this:

```
FtlProcessingController ctrl = new FtlProcessingController();
ctrl.process(TEMPLATES, OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, root, metadata);
```

I'm not the author of this **FtlProcessingController** class, but the *process* method basically takes the template files from the *TEMPLATES* directory, fills them with what's inside the *root* object (a tree of Answer objects) and the `metadata` object (a Map of additional data), and ouputs the .xml files to *OUTPUT*_ *DIRECTORY*.

Briefly, the main code looks like this:

```
// Prepare files and data

FtlProcessingController ctrl = new FtlProcessingController();
ctrl.process(TEMPLATES, OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, root, metadata);

// Validate XML files
```

**The problem is** any console output after the *process* call does not work; nothing shows up in the console.

I tried surrounding the call with some test output and saving the `PrintStream` for a reset:

```
System.out.println("Console");
PrintStream stdOut = System.out;

FtlProcessingController ctrl = new FtlProcessingController();
ctrl.process(TEMPLATES, OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, root, metadata);

// Test Exception was thrown here.

System.setOut(stdOut);
System.out.println("Console again");
```

but I only get:

> Console

I know for sure that there is no *infinite loop* or *System.exit()* in this call, since the files are successfully generated. I even tried throwing an **Exception** right after the call to confirm that, and the Exception was thrown normally.

**My question is**: independently of what the *process* method does or doesn't do with **System.out**, shouldn't I be able to print again on the console after the `System.setOut(stdOut)` call?

What could be possibly messing up the standard output so that the saved PrintStream doesn't work?

Thanks!

Full main code, for the curious:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Parse answers
        Answer root = AnswerUtils.fromJSON(JSON_FILE, Answer.class);

        ModuleInfo manager = new SimpleModuleInfo(MODULE_MANAGER_ID, MODULE_MANAGER_CATEGORY, MODULE_MANAGER_NAME,
                MODULE_MANAGER_VERSION, MODULE_MANAGER_VERSION);
        ModuleInfo module = new SimpleModuleInfo(MODULE_ID, MODULE_CATEGORY, MODULE_NAME, MODULE_VERSION, INSTANCE);

        List<ModuleInfo> info = new ArrayList<ModuleInfo>();
        info.add(manager);
        info.add(module);
        if (DEPENDENCIES_FILES != null) {
            // property file, with all dependencies as a comma-separated value under the 'dependencies' key
            Properties props = new Properties();
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = new FileInputStream(DEPENDENCIES_FILES);
                props.load(in);
            } finally {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
            }
            String[] values = StringUtils.split(props.getProperty("dependencies"), ',');
            if (values != null) {
                for (String value : values) {
                    ModuleDependency dep = new ModuleDependency(StringUtils.trim(value));
                    info.add(new SimpleModuleInfo(dep.getIdentifier(), "Category", WordUtils.capitalizeFully(
                            dep.getIdentifier(), new char[] { '-' }), dep.getVersion().toString(), dep
                            .isInstanceDependency() ? module.getInstance() : "Default"));
                }
            }
        }
        Map<String, Object> metadata = getMetadata(HOME, os, arch, module, info.toArray(new ModuleInfo[info.size()]));

        System.out.println("Console");
        PrintStream stdOut = System.out;

        FtlProcessingController ctrl = new FtlProcessingController();
        ctrl.process(TEMPLATES, OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, root, metadata);

        System.setOut(stdOut);
        System.out.println("Console again");

        // Validate XML
        Collection<File> xmlFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, OUTPUT_FILES_EXTENSIONS, WITH_SUBDIRECTORIES);
        for (File file : xmlFiles) {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setValidating(false);
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            factory.setFeature(FACTORY_DTD_FEATURE, false);

            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

            XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
            reader.setErrorHandler(new SPErrorHandler());
            reader.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        if(true)
            throw new IOException();
    } catch (SAXException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you flush the output stream after printing "Console again"?

Comment: Without knowing more about `FtlProcessingController` it's going to be hard to help.

Comment: It is possible that the method you call reassigns the System.out stream. If that is the case and output is no longer visible in the Java console it maybe that the output is written to a log file. This approach for logging is, however, an extremely bad idea and one shouldn't do it. An idea even worse than that would be to actually close the System.out stream. Do you have access to the source code of the FtlProcessingController class?

Comment: @Kallja I just dived into FtlProcessingController with my coworker, and we actually found out that the System.out gets closed somewhere inside, like you said. I didn't even know such a thing was possible, and it's pretty embarrassing to work with now...

Comment: @AlexisLeclerc Well, then I'm going to post my comment as an answer, which you can accept, if you don't mind. My inner karma-wh*** get's to go to bed happy. :)

Comment: There you go, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the method you call reassigns the `System.out` stream, which can be done with the `System.setOut(PrintStream)` method.

If that is the case and output is no longer visible in the Java console it maybe that the output is written to a log file. This approach for logging is, however, an extremely bad idea and one shouldn't do it especially in a library that others may end up using.

An idea even worse than that would be to actually close the `System.out` stream. I can't think of any scenario justifying doing this.

Comment: As additional information, I found a question related to a closed System.out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941298/system-out-closed-can-i-reopen-it