# Restoring the System.out - PrintStream

Tags: java, system.out

I recently recognized that you're able to close the PrintStream `System.out`!

So the code snippet:

```
System.out.println("foo");
System.out.close();
System.out.println("bar");
```

will produce the output:

```
foo
```

instead of:

```
foo
bar
```

---

Now to my question:

**Is there a way to restore the PrintStream after closing it?**

I've seen there's a `setOut(PrintStream p)` method in `System` which allows me to set the System.out stream to some other stream. But i don't know how to create a stream that's printing to console!

---

Once again, my question is NOT if i can reopen the `System.out` printstream! I'm asking if one could reproduce the steps that java is doing internally to open a `PrintStream` that is printing to the console AFTER the `System.out` PrintStream was closed!

Comment: A closed stream cannot perform output operations and cannot be reopened

Comment: Well i might have written this question badly. I'm aware that a closed stream is closed forever but i'd like to know if I can restore it to default somehow (e.g. there's a `setOut()` method which allows me to set a PrintStream as System.out, but i don't know how to create a Printstream that prints to console!)

Comment: @ParkerHalo I tried to recreate what System class does internally - `FileOutputStream fdOut = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);System.setOut(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fdOut, 128), true));` but it didn't work. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: @Eran that's some nice idea! I'll try to play around with that a bit!

Comment: @Eran problem seems to be that `System.out.close()` somehow changes something at the `FileDescriptor.out`... Before the close, the `FileDescriptor.out` is valid and afterwards it's not...

Comment: @ParkerHalo Try to create a new descripor - `FileDescriptor desc = new FileDescriptor();
        desc.handle = set(1);`

Comment: hmmm... the handle is private and FileDescriptor cannot be subclassed...

Comment: @Eran agreed! But thanks for trying ;)!

Comment: here a nice explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941298/system-out-closed-can-i-reopen-it

Comment: @Csanesz i know i could just NOT close the stream... I'm very aware of that... My question is if there's any way to reopen it by myself. But we're stuck at some point there becaue the handle of FileDescriptor is private and cannot be changed!

Comment: What if you just disable `close` for `System.out` and `System.err`?